# Select rows in excel in a series

Tags: rows, series

Well, I have a data base of 500 people, and I want to select rows in series.

I need to extract 60 rows in an order like, number 3, number 11, number 19 and so on.

Does anyone have any ideeas? :-?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: well, besides picking them manually and copying them into another sheet I haven`t really tried anything else. Searched for answers but I can`t really find one :-?